# 'E: Unable to locate package fluxgui' error while installing fluxgui

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

[image]

i was following these instructions to install flux for linux.

this was the output of sudo apt-get update
[image]

and this was the output of sudo install

[image]

if someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

For those of you failing to install flux even after trying, like me, you could install redshift instead. Just type the following commands in your Ubuntu terminal:

1. `sudo apt-get install redshift`
2. `redshift -O 3500` (type in any number between 1000 to 5500 according to your preference)

[You can start from 2nd point in order to find out if redshift is already installed]

To remove the effects of redshift type:

3. `redshift -x`